# How to get the relative position of a Dictionary element?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the next C# code:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    d.Add("a", 3);
    d.Add("b", 1);
    d.Add("c", 0);
    d.Add("d", -1);
    d.Add("e", -9);
```

When searching the key "c" I want to get the position of this key, i.e. 2. If I look for the key "e", I want to get 4. If the element is not found the relative position could be -1.

Added:
Unless you have a better idea, I want to populate a matrix with certain values in a row  number indicated by the relative position of a dictionary element found. The same applies for the column but using a different dictionary. An example:

```
     n4   n2   n1   n3  n9  . . . 
a   4/4
b              2         8
c
d                  8/2
e         4/3
.
.
.
```

Where a,b,c,d,e,... are the keys of dictionay "d" and n4,n2,n3,n9 are the keys of a second dictionary.

How can I get this?

Comment: Why would you need something like this? It's an implementation detail that only matters if the implementation uses indexing (which it might not).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "position" within a `Dictionary<,>` - it's an unordered collection.

There are similar collections sorted by key - [`SortedList<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) and [`SortedDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx). Note that those are ordered by key rather than insertion time though. It's not clear which you want.

Comment: Jon, thanks for you answer, I added what I want in the question; hope it helps for the answer. My best regards.

Comment: @user255053: I'm afraid it's still not really clear what you mean by "relative position". Should this be determined by the key, or the order in which the entries were inserted?

Comment: Jon, very sorry if I was not clear. I added an example of the results I want to get, the values of the matrix are arbitrary and, as you can see, not all the cells of this matrix gets filled.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm surprised to be saying this, but I think I disagree with you that there is no such thing as position in a Dictionary. Dictionary.ElemantAt(int) is getting the element at a particular position, therefore the concept of position must exist. Whether or not the positions are meaningful is another question. (Though it appears that they do represent order of insertion.)

Comment: @TTT: The documentation explicitly states: "The order in which the items are returned is undefined." It can change at any time. It's like trying to attach meaning to the value returned by `GetHashCode`- you can do it if you like, but it's a really bad idea. It would be *entirely reasonable* for the value returned by `ElementAt(0)` to change between two calls. Yes, there's a way that you can *view* it as an ordered collection, but doing so is a bad idea because ordering is in no way inherent in the concept of the collection.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I completely agree with your comment. I suppose my original disagreement was more semantically speaking. There is a "position", but perhaps not a "meaningful position". And because the position actually exists, the OP's question can be answered. I took a stab at it below with the obvious caveat of questioning the validity of trusting it to be persistant.

Comment: @TTT: Suppose the position changed between calls, even without any *mutation* of the dictionary (it doesn't right now, but it could) - so using `ElementAt(0)` effectively returned a random element. What's the position of any element then? Effectively that is a meaningless *question* IMO. I think it's better to call that out explicitly. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If I wanted to defend my argument, I would say even a random position every time is still a position, albeit a completely meaningless position. I don't want to defend my argument though, since I agree nothing in the docs precludes that from happening.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
d.Keys.ToList().IndexOf("c");
```

Please Note that the O(1) time lookup offered by the Dictionary is lost when converting to the List, because Lists are inherently O(n). So if your Dictionary has a large number of elements, you're probably better off using another Dictionary or Matrix dimension to store the positions, since retrieving them in this manner will likely be slower. In fact, you should probably assume that the one-liner above is similar to:

```
GetDictKeyPos(d, "c");

public int GetDictKeyPos(Dictionary<string, int> d, string key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (d.ElementAt(i).Key == key)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**As a side note**, if you are trying to get the position, you're probably making the assumption that the position is preserved. Microsoft says don't count on it, but in practice you'll discover that you probably can count on it. (I've never seen position not be preserved.) That being said, until Microsoft admits that, "Yeah, yeah, we've been holding out on you: position actually is preserved in a Dictionary. We just didn't want to admit it because we wanted to be able to change it if we found a better implementation, but now we know we're going to leave it, so here ya go...", you probably shouldn't assume that position is preserved.

Lastly, if you are planning to take your chances and assume it's preserved, and you also plan to use the above method to get the position, then consider storing the keys in a List instead, since the lookup time will be the same, and List order is guaranteed to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have no implied order of key-value pairs. If you need the "position," you are using them the wrong way.

*On your edit:* If you are implementing a matrix, your best bet would be to use a multidimensional array. Eg:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[3, 2] { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
```

Is equivalent to a matrix like:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

You can access its elements using `matrix[i][j]`; eg `matrix[0][0]` is 1, `matrix[0][1]` is 2, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I thought in that solution but I wanted to know if I could find a better and generic way, because according to the addition I did to the question, I use a second diccionary that is <string, string> and I also need to know the relative position. Regards.

Comment: @user Why don't you just use a multidimensional array of strings?

Comment: I modified my question again to give an example of what I want. I realy thank your for your patiente and help.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use any of the builtin collection data structures including `KeyedCollection`. However, you can easily make your own collection class by deriving from `Collection` and which contains a `Dictionary` internally for quick lookups on the key. The `Collection` class itself provides the ability for indexed retrieval.

```
public class KeyValueCollection<TKey, TValue> : Collection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public TValue GetValue(TKey key)
    {
        return m_Dictionary[key];
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        m_Dictionary.Add(key, value);
        base.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        m_Dictionary.Clear();
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        m_Dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {

        m_Dictionary.Remove(this[index].Key);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        m_Dictionary[this[index].Key] = item.Value;
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are really looking for that functionality, why don't you maintain an auxilary data structure which maintains the order in which you added the elements

(OR)

Probably you want to just maintain a List of Structures which store

```
   [{"a",-1},{"b",1},{"c",0},{"d",-1},{"e",-9}]
```